LineageOS and /e/OS fail to detect SIM card in 2 Xperia XZ2c devices
For my Sony Xperia xz2 compact I used the LOS builds for years. At June 28th, the GSM stopped working caused by missing sim.

I went back to lineage-21.0-20240621-nightly-xz2c
I ordered a new SIM card from my provider -> not detected
I took another xz2c device -> same phenomenon
I tried lineage-21.0-20240706-nightly-xz2c and lineage-21.0-20240712-nightly-xz2c -> still SIM not detected
SONY Xperia z3c (with outdated LOS) and iPhone 11 -> SIM detected
Installed /e/OS on xz2c -> SIM not detected

To sum up: SIM seems to be okay. Two devices of the same type with different Android-bases OSs cannot detect (more than one) SIM Card. I doubt an identical hardware crash in two independent devices at the same time. Any ideas for further investigations? Any chance that there is a systematic bug in the current android-based builds? Any similar experiences with xz2c?

Have you tried to find a log that shed some light onto the problem? If I am not mistaken the RIL should be the one communicating with the SIM card. Trying to "wiretap" (on software level) the APDU communication with the SIM may also be helpful to see which command is going wrong.

I have the same problem. I have not yet found a solution. I run lineage-21.0-20240720-nightly-xz2c. I tried the suggestions here: 1. Enter the APN details manually (which I cannot because the system will not allow me to enter these details because the system detects no sim card) 2. Remove the lock screen & password altogether (which does not fix the issue). I also tried cleaning the surface of the sim card and even lightly sanding it down. The problem doesn't seem to be hardware related though. I can confirm sim is still working in another phone.

I just installed lineage-21.0-20240720-nightly-xz2c (from stock image) and in the first run the sim card was detected and worked. But after the first reboot, no sim card detected. This has been the case for 2 days now. I tried installing the previous version lineage-21.0-20240712-nightly-xz2c, but no luck.

@user434586 - thanks for sharing. Another hint that it is not a hardware damage but a structural bug.

Now, this issue is tracked here: https://gitlab.com/LineageOS/issues/android/-/issues/7474
